# Convert time to millisecond and find out time period in java or android

Tags: android, datetime

I have enter earlier time period just like this, 2012-01-18-11-42-24 in database, So How to convert this time in to millisecond, I have so confused,  I have try many way but could not get this time in millisecond.

My final aim is to find out time period 2012-04-18-11-42-24 time and current time.Please give so idea, How to?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public long convertDateToMillis(int day, int month, int year, int hour, int minute)
{
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, 00);    
       return c.getTimeInMillis();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) classes. They have a `parse(String string)` method that will give you a `Date` object from its `String` representation. You can then use `getTime()` method to get the time as milliseconds and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
 Date c_date=new Date(); //current date 
 Date saved_date=(Date)outputFormat.parse("2012-01-18-11-42-24");   //saved date
 long diffInMs = c_date.getTime() -saved_date.getTime();  //diff between two in milisecond
 long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMs);  //millisecond to second convertion
```

you can either use as same as saved_date for the second one date instead of current date and than same way find time period between two

Answer (score 0):

***use this code to get time in milliseconds***

```
Date  date1 = new Date(datepicker.getYear() - 1900, datepicker.getMonth(), datepicker.getDayOfMonth(), timepicker.getCurrentHour()*3600000, timepicker.getCurrentMinute()*60000);
Log.i(TAG, date1.toString());
```