# How can I get default Date and Time format pattern

Tags: java, android

Could somebody tell me how can I get the default date and time format pattern(String) for specified locale(or default locale).

What I already found (Could be useful for somebody else):

1. How to get default locale.

   ```java
   Locale currentLocale= Locale.getDefault();
   System.out.print(currentLocale.toString());

   Result is "en_US"
   ```
2. How to get decimal separator.

   ```java
   DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols =
                                        new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
   System.out.print(decimalFormatSymbols.getDecimalSeparator());

   Result is "."
   ```
3. How to get the default Date and Time format pattern (String);

   ```java
   (do something)
   System.out.print(something);
   And got at output something like this: "dd/mm/yyyy" or "hh:mm:ss".. 
                                or other values for specified locale.
   ```

Thanks a lot.

**UPD:**
Found solution:

```java
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
String dateLocalizedFormatPattern = simpleDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern();

The result of System.out.print(dateLocalizedFormatPattern) 
                                             on my device is "M/d/yy h:mm a".
```

Comment: check my answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204291/convert-time-to-millisecond-and-find-out-time-period-in-java-or-android/10204628#10204628

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

As Russian Bear mentions in his update to the question there is a `toLocalizedPattern()` method in `SimpleDateFormat` that returns the format string.

**Original answer**

`SimpleDateFormat`uses the following code in it's private constructor:

```js
...
ResourceBundle r = LocaleData.getDateFormatData(loc);
if (!isGregorianCalendar()) {
    try {
        dateTimePatterns = r.getStringArray(getCalendarName() + ".DateTimePatterns");
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
    }
}
if (dateTimePatterns == null) {
    dateTimePatterns = r.getStringArray("DateTimePatterns");
}
...
```

So the actual format strings seems to be in a `ResourceBundle`accessed via the `LocaleData.getDateFormatData()`method.

Unfortunately the `LocaleData`class is a part of the internal `sun.util.resources` package.

Comment: But I see that you found the actual solution that i missed in SimpleDateFormat :-)

Comment: What if I just want to print out the date part say `M/d/yy` without the time part, as in the sample output: `h:mm a`?

Comment: I guess you could do `dateLocalizedFormatPattern.split(" ")[0]`, but that will only work if the format separates the date and the time part with a space. I don't know whether there is a generic way to get just the date part from a date format.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use the `DateFormat` class. Check out the [`getDateInstance(int, Locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance%28int,%20java.util.Locale%29) method.